# Function declaration in js target.extend

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I do not really know how to ask the question and feel free to aks me precisions (kindly, if possible).

I have something like :

```
define([...],function(...) {
  return function (target) {
    return target.extend({
      someFunction : function() {...},
      someOtherFunction() {...}
    });
});
```

What is the difference between someFunction and someOtherFunction ? If there is not any, what is the prefered one ?

Maybe you have a link about this and terminology.

If it is of any help, it is in a project with Magento2 (***requirejs***, *jquery* and *knockout* for JS).

Comment: Are you using any framework for your work? (Looks like Magento...?) If so, you could have a better chance to get answers by adding a tag with your framework name. Sorry, I don't think I have knowledge to answer your question. Good luck!

Comment: It's magento but I did not think it could be related, it's why I was more general.